# Unable to change package footprint solder pad size in eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, layout, footprint

as the image shows, I want to change the BGA soldering dots from current size to something larger. Only size changes, or shall we say diameter changes, no shape or anything, but I couldn't.

I clicked change tool, entered the new diameter (and I'm sure it's different than the original) and then clicked the pads I wanted to change, nothing happens.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is your screen shot from the component's library package or from the main PCB layout view?

Comment: Looking at it I believe your footprint has a circle drawn on the tstop layer which is why you see diameter setting when you look at info. The pad itself should have two properties, one for SMD Size which changes the overall size of the copper pad, and a second for roundness which will be set to 100% (I.e. circle - 0% would be square).

Comment: Tom my goodness you are so right I modified SMD and it worked! Thank you! Can I convert this to answer?

Comment: @MattCox didn't see your reply last March. Only noticed it now as the question was bumped to the front page.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it your footprint uses a circle drawn on the `tstop` layer which is why you see diameter setting when you look at info.

The pad itself is actually an SMD pad, which does not have a diameter setting. Instead it has two key properties:

- `SMD Size` which changes the overall size of the copper pad
- `roundness` which will be set to 100% (i.e. circle - 0% would be square)

So to change the size, leave the roundness set at 100%, and change the `SMD size` setting, making sure to keep both the width and length of the pad the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Info tool (the button that is the letter i), click on the PTH you are interested in and adjust the Diameter from auto to another value that is greater than your Drill size. Click Apply and visually inspect the hole - if it's still not as much copper as you want, increase the Diameter again until it's as thick as you want.

For reference see this link...
[Reference link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBao0eHu3SQ)

Comment: Hello, I info-ed the pad, no option/input box for "diameter".

Comment: @MattCox...I just posted link in my answer. See that and do according to that.

Comment: Hello I watched that video 4 hours ago, didn't work ;(

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to make changes to a particular part in pcb layout...

edit the part in its library and make your changes then update this library in the pcb layout...